# excel read in python empty datafrmae

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel('file3.xlsx')
print(x)
```

when I run this I get an answer like the following:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-114.31190317508207, -115.47192812345514 ]
[0 rows x 2 columns]
```

please help me regarding this issue

Comment: share you .xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the excel sheet also, which you have not done, like so:

```
df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
```

here the parameter `sheetname` must be the name of the excel sheet what you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

data=pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Data')

make sure your sheet name is correct and try using full file path

Comment: import xlrd;                            
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file) ;                  
workbook.nsheets ;                    
workbook.sheet_names();                                                                                                   Alternatively try this, helps you find out all sheet names